# wordpress database: mysql #1064

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 for query SELECT count FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = made by require('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), include('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\mesocolumn\front-page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\mesocolumn\lib\templates\home-feat-cat.php'), dez_get_cat_post_count

WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 for query SELECT count FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = made by require('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), include('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\mesocolumn\front-page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\mesocolumn\lib\templates\home-feat-cat.php'), dez_get_cat_post_count

WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 for query SELECT count FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = made by require('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), include('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\mesocolumn\front-page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\mesocolumn\lib\templates\home-feat-cat.php'), dez_get_cat_post_count

WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 for query SELECT count FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = made by require('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), include('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\mesocolumn\front-page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('C:\inetpub\vhosts\sristudentsolutions.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\mesocolumn\lib\templates\home-feat-cat.php'), dez_get_cat_post_count

I have count column in the table also.  what could be the reason for this error. please help as soon as possible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just an error message pasted as a question, making no effort to format it or identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The query you execute

```
SELECT count FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id =
```

misses am actual `term_id` at the end. It should probably look like this:

```
SELECT `count` FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = 12345
```

Comment: I do have a count column in the table. what could be the other reasons for such errors please mention with solution.

Comment: @KiranRaj please read the updated answer.

Comment: i have tested the error query with the changes you asked to make. but no use. It worked fine in my local server without any changes, but when i uploaded the site online, this error occurred.  is this the problem with my new host?  please visit http://sristudentsolutions.com and scroll down.

Comment: Also, although `count` is not a reserved word, using a keyword such as this is IMO just asking for trouble

Comment: It's a template from wordpress and all I did is,just edit and FTP.

Comment: addition:  It appears only on my homepage, not in any other pages.

Comment: i understood where the problem is, it is in giving term id or that using the command made by require.  please help how i can modify that sql command!

Comment: Ask another question and put everything in there that people need to know about your problem. And format your question properly.